# How to restrict only video upload using javascript or Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, file-upload, video-processing

Hi I have one requirement where I am expecting a lot of video upload traffic but I want to make sure the uploaded file only are videos.

I have not used any uploader plugin for some specific reason.

```
<input type="file" id="upload" class="btn btn-blue" style="height: 35px;" name="file" /><br />
```

I am using simple html file type input and I want to restrict only video upload.

I have tried checking extensions but It's lot of extension and difficult to check each one of it.

http://www.fileinfo.com/filetypes/video

Any idea on this?

Comment: you can do the following : when the user clicks the submit button to upload the video,Use jQuery to determine the file extension i.e allow the file to be uploaded only if the file extension is .mp4 or .avi etc... if not then use event.preventdefault() followed by a message that only video files should be uploaded

Comment: to check with I guess 150 + video extensions are not a good way to restrict.

Comment: then try some regular expression in the process i have mentioned maybe that will help

Answer (score 1):

There is no way you can restrict the upload on client side. You should be using server side validation for doing such validations.

You can set the **[accept attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_accept.asp)** as video for input type file. this only show the file-type filtering based on MIME type for the file-select which can be changed by user :

```
<input type="file" accept="video/*">
```

for setting through JS:

```
document.getElementById("upload").accept = "video/*";
```

Comment: Notice: `accept` video/* attribute is valid from HTML5 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input means that still in 2014 IE8,9 are to take in serious consideration.

Comment: If I use accept attribute it will not restrict me. In browse window I can select all files and select any non video file.